# Linq query returning values not equal to query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having an interesting problem.  I am running a linq query on some items returned to a model.  Here is the method so I can walk through:

In the  PainCategory database is:

```
Id      Title       CompanyId
1        Type           1
2        Priority       1
3        Likelihood     1
4        Type           2
5        Priority       2
6        Likelihood     2
```

When I run this query I am getting a false comparison:

```
 int compId = 0;
            //get project by id
            if (item.ProjectId != 0)
            {
                Userclient = new RestClient("http:www.website.com/id");
                var projReq = new RestRequest("project/{id}", Method.GET);
                projReq.AddUrlSegment("id", item.ProjectId.ToString());
                projReq.AddHeader("id", id);
                projReq.AddHeader("key", Key);
                projReq.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                var projResponse = Userclient.Execute(projReq) as RestResponse;
                ProjectDTO d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectDTO>(projResponse.Content);

                compId = d.CompanyId;
            }

            foreach(var i in defectsToReturn)
            {
                i.PainCategories = db.PainCategories.ToList().Where(p => p.CompanyId == compId);
            }
```

So the `if (item.ProjectId != 0){`statement just does a RestSharp call to an api and sets compId to 1.

inside my foreach statement when i debug... the compId has the value of 1 as well.  But the i.PainCategories contains all 6 elements of the PainCategories table even though 3 of the values for companyId are set to 2.  Any idea on why this is happening?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wit seems that the filter doesn't work for your `List`. Instead of :

```
i.PainCategories = db.PainCategories.ToList().Where(p => p.CompanyId == compId);
```

Could you apply the filter before the `List` conversion.

```
i.PainCategories = db.PainCategories.Where(p => p.CompanyId == compId).ToList();
```

Just have a try.

Comment: Same result but thank you for attempt.  I noticed that when it goes through the foreach loop it i.paincategories gets a count of 3 each time.  This could effect the outcome if all 6 with companyid equal to 1.